# Google visualization datatable filterRows

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, filtering

I have a sample google visualization datatable [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/xx9386me/) where I can filter the rows of datatable as,

```
 var rows= data.getFilteredRows([{column: 2, value: 'Mountain View' }]);
   console.log(rows);
```

Which will return the row Index which contains the exact value `Mountain View`. But is it possible to filter the rows whose value contains some string like `le` as

```
 var rows2= data.getFilteredRows([{column: 2, value: 'le' }]);
    console.log(rows2);
```

which can return the row indexes `1` and `7`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use [test](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference) property of getFilteredRows.

```
var rows2 = data.getFilteredRows([{
   column: 2,
   test: function (value, row, column, table) {
        return (value.indexOf("le") > 0)
      }
  }]);
 console.log(rows2);
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xx9386me/3/)**